# How do you set up an FTP server on a computer?

Tags: ftp

Furthermore, how do you check a server to see if an ftp server is running on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open your favorite ftp client, specify server url and click connect. If connection successful then ftp is installed and started on a server.

You can do even from windows console, just type something like (open Run dialog by pressing Win+R): cmd /K ftp {serverurl}

Comment: Thanks.  So how can I set up an FTP server on a computer?

Comment: It depends on which operating system is running on a computer. For Windows, you can install Fillzilla available at http://filezilla-project.org/.

Comment: There is also CoreFTP for Windows. www.coreftp.com/download.html

Comment: When I set up ftp on a server can I set it up to use a domain user account for logging in rather than a local one?

Comment: CoreFTP and FileZilla doesn't support domain authorization. Try Microsoft IIS.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following steps

1. Press Win+R
2. type inetmgr and press enter
3. it opens IIS
4. expand the list and if you find "FTP Sites" folder available then FTP is installed in your system
5. to check if ftp server is running or not expand "FTP sites" folder
6. u will find a sub directory "Default FTP Site".
7. right click on that subdirectory and you will find 'start','stop' and 'pause' options available there
8. if start option is disabled then ftp server is running on your system
9. you can also start it if not already started

To install FTP. just go to Add/Remove windows component and re install IIS with FTP services and you r done

to check ftp if ftp server is running or not on a remote computer
open your cmd and type ftp and press enter. then use command "open 172.25.65.788" or u can use your own ip address. if it asks for username and password that means server is running.